# Find Surrounding Indexed Records based on a Search of a Separate Field within Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Basically, I'm trying to create a "roll finder" which works on a table of stock movements.
There is an assigned index value from 0, 1, 2 based on certain criteria.

I'm trying to work out how a user could search by a piece number and that piece number corresponds to a set index value (lets say index value 100 for instance) and filter the dataset to only display 10 records before and after the selected value (or 90 - 110 index value).

The input would be piece number and would change based on what they were looking for. I care less about the entry itself but the surrounding entries based on the user input.

Nothing special with the dataset; I'm at a loss where to begin on this one.

[image]

Per comment output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an independent parameter table to use in a slicer where the user selects a particular index. Then filter your visual with a measure like this

```
ShowRow =
IF (
    ABS ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Index] ) - SELECTEDVALUE ( Parameter[Index] ) ) <= 10,
    1,
    0
)
```

(You'd set ShowRow is 1 in the filter pane.)

---

**Edit:** If the user input is the SKU, then the parameter table should be SKU values.

```
ParamSKU = VALUES ( Table1[SKU] )
```

In this case, you need to find the corresponding index before comparing.

```
ShowRow =
VAR SKU = SELECTEDVALUE ( ParamSKU[SKU] )
VAR ParamIndex = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Table1[Index] ), ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[SKU] = SKU )
VAR CurrIndex = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Index] )
RETURN
    IF ( ABS ( CurrIndex - ParamIndex ) <= 10, 1, 0 )
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the parameter table? That would be a virtual table copy of my table1 or?

Comment: A new calculated table like `Parameter = VALUES ( Table1[Index] )` should be fine.

Comment: added an example of the output; still can't seem to get it to work. i see what you're doing there but I'm not sure why the selected value isn't 27...?

Comment: I don't see where you selected 27 from the new parameter table.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I didn't specify; user input is piece number but the index value derived from that search ideally filters the index (+/-10) relative to that piece number

Comment: Great job; this was driving me crazy. Love the approach